# How to force Gradle 'processResources" task to always run

Tags: gradle, dependencies

I am working on a Gradle project, have added a task to the build.gradle to run the gitProperties task (com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties).

It builds the output file just fine, but I need the processResources task to always run after the generateGitProperties task. Whenever I run the build, processResources shows UP-TO-DATE.

```
task printGitProperties { // make sure generateGitProperties task to execute before accessing generated properties
    dependsOn generateGitProperties
    doLast {
        println project.ext.gitProps
    }
}

gitProperties {
    gitPropertiesResourceDir = file("${project.rootDir}/src/main/deploy")
    extProperty = 'gitProps'
    println tasks
}
generateGitProperties.outputs.upToDateWhen { false } // make sure the generateGitProperties task always executes (even when git.properties is not changed)
generateGitProperties.finalizedBy printGitProperties

tasks.processResources.dependsOn generateGitProperties.gitProperties

tasks.findByName('processResources').mustRunAfter 'generateGitProperties'
//tasks.processResources.dependsOn(generateGitProperties)
```

How do I force processResources to always run? The commented code is just a fraction of everything I have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tasks.processResources.outputs.upToDateWhen { false }`